# How to set input text be shown inline with css?

Tags: html, css

I try to make inputs be displayed one after another in line using float: right.

```
[input][input][input]
```

But instead of it i see steps:

```
[input]
       [input]
               [input]
```

Do anyone has any suggestions? I use labels in form as following

here is my code:

כותרת נוספת

```
    <label for="pa_passport">מספר ת.ז</label>
        <input type="text" name="pa_passport" id="pa_passport" placeholder="מספר ת.ז" /><br />

    <label for="pa_firstName">שם פרטי</label>
        <input type="text" name="pa_firstName" id="pa_firstName" placeholder="שם פרטי" /><br />

    <label for="pa_lastName">שם משפחה</label>
        <input type="text" name="pa_lastName" id="pa_lastName" placeholder="שם משפחה" /><br />

    <div style="clear:both"> </div>

    <label for="pa_city">עיר מגורים</label>
        <input type="text" name="pa_city" id="pa_city" placeholder="עיר מגורים" /><br />

    <label for="pa_car">מספר רכב</label>
        <input type="text" name="pa_car" id="pa_car" placeholder="מספר רכב" /><br />

    <label for="pa_city">שנת ייצור</label>
        <input type="text" name="pa_year" id="pa_year" placeholder="שנת ייצור" /><br />

    <h4 class="faqlike bluecolh2">כותרת נוספת</h4>

       <label for="pa_phone">טלפון</label>
        <input type="text" name="pa_phone" id="pa_phone" placeholder="טלפון" /><br />
       <label for="pa_phone"></label>
        <select>
            <option>054</option>
            <option>052</option>
            <option>053</option>
            <option>050</option>
            <option>08</option>
            <option>09</option>
        </select>
```

===UPDATE=====

Here is my scss:

```
.private_area {
    label {
       display:none;            
    }
    input[type=text] {
       float: right;            
    }
}
```

Comment: @TilwinJoy The css has one line: input[type=text] {float:right}

Comment: do you want the labels on top or on the side? anyways you have a <br> between them so that's why the line breaks also.. here's your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/LmDSX/ (update that fiddle to illustrate your problem)

Comment: @webkit OH! Thanks man! So stupid mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want right?

```
body { direction:rtl;}
H4    { clear:both; padding:20px 0;}
label { display:inline-block; width: 70px; margin:0 5px 0 0;}
.field { float:right;}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LmDSX/1/)

let me know if you have any questions :) בהצלחה

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the break statement after each input.